# Auto publishing WCF services to IIS7 from a TeamCity build server

Tags: wcf, iis-7, msbuild, teamcity

I have a bunch of C# VS2010 projects compiling automatically on a TeamCity build server.
The build server compiles the projects and then runs automatic unit tests on the output.
Problem is, part of the tests are trying to communicate with WCF services on the local server.

The tests fail because the BuildServer only builds the projects and does not publish the output services onto the IIS7(Running alongside with the TeamCity).
Is there a simple way to automatically tell TeamCity(maybe through MSBuild.exe) to publish my *.svc files every time the code finished compiling?

Thank you [=

Answer (score 0):

Simplest thing to do would be to point IIS7 at the TeamCity checkout directories -- it will build there so you can run the tests against the services without simulating deployment. You also might want to create 2 stages of tests -- one more traditional unit tests that get run before "deployment" and a 2nd set that gets run after the 1st set is successful and "deployment" happens.

Deploying out of TeamCity can definitely work though exactly how depends on your network and application topography.

Answer (score 0):

To deploy the web services you can use Web Deploy to package and install your services in IIS. However, it seems that the real issue is the dependency your tests have on your services. You should abstract your service interfaces and use a mocking framework and your favourite DI container in your tests so the services don't need to be up.

HTH.